# Remove escape sequence characters like newline, tab and carriage return from JSON file

Tags: json, shell, unix, jq, control-characters

I have a JSON with 80+ fields. While extracting the message field in the below mentioned JSON file using jq, I'm getting newline characters and tab spaces. I want to remove the escape sequence characters and I have tried it using sed, but it did not work.

Sample JSON file:

```
{
"HOSTNAME":"server1.example",
"level":"WARN",
"level_value":30000,
"logger_name":"server1.example.adapter",
"content":{"message":"ERROR LALALLA\nERROR INFO NANANAN\tSOME MORE ERROR INFO\nBABABABABABBA\n BABABABA\t ABABBABAA\n\n BABABABAB\n\n"}
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: so you **never** want a new-line or tab char in that file? OR are there multiple entries in one file? (Please update your Q, and I will delete this comment). Good luck.

Comment: If you use the `-r` option, `jq` will translate escape sequences into real newlines, tabs etc. Is that what you want? `jq -r .content.message file.json`?

Comment: No I want to remove the newline and tab spaces

Comment: For clarity, please add the expected output matching the sample input to your question (one remaining ambiguity is whether you want the enclosing double quotes stripped as well or not).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A **pure `jq` solution**:

```
$ jq -r '.content.message | gsub("[\\n\\t]"; "")' file.json
ERROR LALALLAERROR INFO NANANANSOME MORE ERROR INFOBABABABABABBA BABABABA ABABBABAA BABABABAB
```

If you want to keep the enlosing `"` characters, omit `-r`.

<sup>Note: [peak's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321859/45375) contains a *generalized* regular expression that matches *all* control characters in the ASCII and Latin-1 Unicode range by way of a [Unicode category specifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), `\p{Cc}`. `jq` uses the [Oniguruma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma) regex engine.</sup>

---

Other solutions, **using an additional utility**, such as `sed` and `tr`.

Using `sed` to unconditionally remove escape sequences `\n` and `t`:

```
$ jq '.content.message' file.json | sed 's/\\[tn]//g'
"ERROR LALALLAERROR INFO NANANANSOME MORE ERROR INFOBABABABABABBA BABABABA ABABBABAA BABABABAB"
```

Note that the enclosing `"` are still there, however.
To remove them, add another substitution to the `sed` command:

```
$ jq '.content.message' file.json | sed 's/\\[tn]//g; s/"\(.*\)"/\1/'
ERROR LALALLAERROR INFO NANANANSOME MORE ERROR INFOBABABABABABBA BABABABA ABABBABAA BABABABAB
```

A simpler option that also removes the enclosing `"` (note: output has no trailing `\n`):

```
$ jq -r '.content.message' file.json | tr -d '\n\t'
ERROR LALALLAERROR INFO NANANANSOME MORE ERROR INFOBABABABABABBA BABABABA ABABBABAA BABABABAB
```

Note how `-r` is used to make `jq` *interpolate* the string (expanding the `\n` and `\t` sequences), which are then removed - as literals - by `tr`.

Answer (score 8):

With your input, the following incantation:

```
$ jq 'walk(if type == "string" then gsub("\\p{Cc}"; "<>") else . end)'
```

produces:

```
{
  "HOSTNAME": "server1.example",
  "content": {
    "message": "ERROR LALALLA<>ERROR INFO NANANAN<>SOME MORE ERROR INFO<>BABABABABABBA<> BABABABA<> ABABBABAA<><> BABABABAB<><>"
  },
  "level": "WARN",
  "level_value": 30000,
  "logger_name": "server1.example.adapter"
}
```

Of course, the above invocation is just illustrative:

- you might not need to use `walk/1` at all.  (`walk/1` walks the input JSON.)
- you might want to use a different character class, or specify a pipeline of `gsub/2` invocations.
- if you simply want to excise the control characters, specify "" as the second argument of `gsub/2`.

If you do want to use `walk/1` but your jq does not have it, then simply add its definition (easily available on the web, such as [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq)) before its invocation.

Comment: ++ for several advanced techniques, but, truthfully, the simple `jq -r '.content.message | gsub("[\\n\\t]"; "")' file.json` solution that _could_ be derived from your answer is obscured by the incidental / generalized information.

Comment: @mklement0 - (1) The question includes the phrase "from JSON file" and mentions a large number of fields. Since it's not clear what is actually needed, I thought a generally useful answer would be more generally useful :-)) (2) The question mentions "escape sequence characters" generally, and TAB, NL and CR specifically, whereas the solution you mention in these comments does not cover all three.

Comment: Fair points - there's often ambiguity in the description itself and inconsistencies between the description and the sample data ("newline characters and tab spaces [sic]" are mentioned alongside "escape sequences"). I personally find your answer very useful and learned from it, but my point was that a "gentler" framing with more context could have helped.

Answer (score 2):

With **jq** v1.6 the following is possible

```
jq -rc ".content.message" file.json
```

Comment: Since only a string value is being extracted, `-c` (`--compact-output`) has no effect here, and your solution doesn't do what the question asks for (removal of newlines and tabs).